# Windows and ApiKey authentication in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and I need to be able to use both Windows and custom Apikey authentication schemes for the same service.

Using Postman, Insomnia I choose NTLM authentication with my Active Directory credentials and use apikey in header. Also I have controller method which has to be authorized by valid NTLM credentials and the valid apikey.

But unfortunately the user successfully authorized by NTLM enters the method with any apikey in header. No matter valid or invalid.

Can anyone help me to find out why I don't see error 401 if apikey is invalid?

Here's my code - controller method

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize("AuthorizePolicy")]
public IActionResult AddToJournal(JournalItem journalItem)
{ 
    // method body 
}
```

Startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthentication(ApiKeyDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddApiKey();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AuthorizePolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ApiKeyDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); 
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            });
        });
```

ApiKey auth handler

```
class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private const string API_KEY_HEADER = "Api-Key";
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock,
        ApplicationDbContext context) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey(API_KEY_HEADER))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Header Not Found.");
        }

        string apiKeyToValidate = Request.Headers[API_KEY_HEADER];

        var apiKey = await _context.UserApiKeys.Include(uak => uak.User)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(uak => uak.Value == apiKeyToValidate);

        if (apiKey == null)
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid key.");
        }

        return AuthenticateResult.Success(CreateTicket(apiKey.User));
    }

    private AuthenticationTicket CreateTicket(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

        return ticket;
    }
}
```

AddApiKey extension

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddApiKey(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(
        ApiKeyDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => { }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code accepts two authentication schemes in parallel. If the user is authenticated by one of them, the system allows him to execute the method.

You are using policy-based authorization, with two different authorization schemes. You need to specify a specific authentication scheme in the AuthorizeAttribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="")]
```

I do not know which default names are used for these authentication schemes.  So I suggest using same names:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddNegotiate("NegotiateScheme");
services.AddAuthentication(ApiKeyDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddApiKey("ApiKeyScheme");

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
             options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("NegotiateScheme", "ApiKeyScheme")
                   .Build();

             options.AddPolicy("AuthorizePolicy", policy =>  policy.Requirements.Add(*what you want*));
         });
```

And after this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKeyScheme", Policy = "AuthorizePolicy")]
public IActionResult AddToJournal(JournalItem journalItem)
{ 
    // method body 
}
```

---

Both of them... So you can try add requirement and handler:

```
public class ApiKeyRequirement: : IAuthorizationRequirement {}


public class ApiKeyHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ApiKeyRequirement>
{
    string apiKeyClaimName = "Api-Key";
    DataBaseContext  _dbContext;

    public ApiKeyHandler(DataBaseContext context)
    {
        this._dbContext = context;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    ApiKeyRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == apiKeyClaimName))
        {
            Guid userId = new Guid(context.User.FindFirst(u => u.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value); //Change type to your ID type
            
            string apiKeyRequest = context.User.FindFirst(u => u.Tupe == apiKeyClaimName).Value;
            string apiKeyDb = this._dbContext.UserApiKeys.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(uak => uak.UserId == userId)?.ApiKeyValue ?? return Task.CompletedTask;

            if(apiKeyRequest.Equals(apiKeyDb))
                context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

At startup you need to add handler to services:

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, ApiKeyHandler>(); // mb AddSingletone be prefer 

services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes("NegotiateScheme", "ApiKeyScheme")
            .Build();

    options.AddPolicy("AuthorizePolicy", policy =>  policy.Requirements.Add(new ApiKeyRequirement()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to use single authentication scheme in Authorize attribute. In this case for ApiKey scheme invalid ntlm password are accepted and method is executed anyway. The goal is to get both identities. One is the ClaimsIdentity from ApiKey Auth. And the second is Windows Identity from NTLM Auth.

Comment: answer has updated :)